# Automatically add newline on save in PyCharm?

Tags: python, newline, pycharm

PyCharm 5 complains of a missing newline at the end of the file:

[image: PEP 8: No newline at end of file]

How do I tell PyCharm to add the newline (if missing) automatically whenever I save a file?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This can be enabled in the `Editor > General` settings:

From the File menu under ☰, pick `Settings...`, then select `Editor > General`. Under the `On Save` section in the right-hand pane, check the `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break` checkbox.

[image: Ensure every saved file ends with a line break (PyCharm 2023.1.2)]

---

For older versions of PyCharm:

From the File pick `Settings`, then select `Editor > General`. Under the `Other` section in the right-hand pane, check the `Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on Save` checkbox.

[image: Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on Save (PyCharm 2020.1.3)]

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't enabled by default in PyCharm?

Comment: Sublime Text works this way too. My guess is the authors made the decision that surprising users who are unaware of the need for the trailing newline was worse than creating extra work for folks who want that behavior enabled in their editor.

Comment: Hmm I don't have an "Other" section in PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3. Will upgrade to the 2017 version and see if it has it.

Comment: "Other" is not a selection in the navigation tree, but rather a section divider in the right-hand pane of `Editor > General`.

Comment: In Pycharm 2020.1.3 the setting is now "Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on Save".

Comment: As of Pycharm 2023.2.2 the setting is called ``Ensure every saved file ends with a line break``

Answer (score 10):

**Newer PyCharm** I believe (2020+):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### (Still valid in 2023)

### PyCharm >= 2021.1

You can now find this setting here:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`.

Comment: This is the answer in 2021.

Comment: Still valid in 2023

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is I create a macro to do three things:

- Reformat code
- Organise imports
- Save all files

This will, indeed, add a newline at the end of each file.
Then I rebind the `Save all` shortcut (`Cmd+S` on Mac) to this macro.

You can read more about macros [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/using-macros-in-the-editor.html?origin=old_help). I also recommend using [Navigate to Action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/navigating-to-action.html?origin=old_help) to find actions you forget the hotkeys for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I found it in PyCharm Community Edition 2017.5. You can go to `Preferences...` and do a search for `ensure line feed`. Under `Editor/General` the `Other` option may not be visible as can be seen here:

[Other is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XNLv.png)

But if you do a search, it finds it:

[Search finds this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icXI0.png)

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a default feature but if it is not enabled:

go to settings > Editor > General

then you will see a checkbox option to select...