# Goland does not add newline at end of file

Tags: go, goland

I am using Goland to write my grpc application. After my proto files are generated, no trailing newline is present at the end of the file. Is there a way to enable this in the IDE?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "End Of File", other than the actual end of the file. Assuming the files are not infinitely large, what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I said it wrong. I meant final newline

Comment: Maybe something from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761227/how-to-make-intellij-idea-insert-a-new-line-at-every-end-of-file?

Comment: PyCharm variant of this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043061/automatically-add-newline-on-save-in-pycharm (all built on the same base)

Comment: IntelliJ version @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761227/how-to-make-intellij-idea-insert-a-new-line-at-every-end-of-file?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AndreyGrigorev, ...btw, have you considered [edit]ing the question to correct the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the time to [read the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/settings-editor-general.html), or explore Goland's settings, you'll discover this under *Settings..Editor..General*:

[image: Ensure every saved file ends with a line break]